# push() property to an object dynamically Typescript/Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, typescript, object

I am trying to `push()` a property to an object `counterType` but I get the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

I am trying to grab specific data from a JSON file and add it to the  `counterType` object. My code below:

```
    let ret = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
    let counterType: any = {};

    for (let i = 0; i < ret.topdownGranularities.TOPDOWN_SYSTEM_DATA.rows.length; i++) {
        let row = ret.topdownGranularities.TOPDOWN_SYSTEM_DATA.rows[i];
        let row_system = row.SYSTEM;
        if (row.hasOwnProperty("SYSTEM")) {
            counterType[row_system].push({ name: row_system, checked: true });
            // counterType[row_system] = "name: " + row_system + ", checked: " + true;
        }
    }
```

This line works but only adds one property each iteration as it's just re-defining the value of `counterType[row_system]` each time to the same thing:

`// counterType[row_system] = "name: " + row_system + ", checked: " + true;`

I want to constantly add `{ name: row_system, checked: true }` to the object each iteration.

Comment: `counterType[row_system]` is undefined.

Comment: You can add a `counterType[row_system] === undefined && (counterType[row_system] = [])` statement before `counterType[row_system].push(...)`.

Comment: @Titus How and why does this work? Is this the only way you know about resolving this issue?

Comment: @StefanNicolaou What this does is to check if `counterType[row_system]` is `undefined` and if it is, set it to an empty array. You can do the same thing using an `if` statement `if(!counterType[row_system]){ counterType[row_system] = []; }`

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
let counterType: any = {};
```

With :

```
let counterType: any = [];
```

Since you are using it as array and push into it.

Also you dont need to set index for pushing :

```
counterType[row_system].push({ name: row_system, checked: true });
```

can be replaced by

```
counterType.push({ name: row_system, checked: true });
```

Comment: I would like to set an index as I will be running similar loops for multiple JSON files and they will all be put into the `counterType` object

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this

```
public interface counterTypesModel ={
   name :any,
   checked : boolean
}
counterTypesArray : counterTypesModel = [];
counterTypesArray.push({'name': row_system,'checked' : true});
```